# Normalized label box for object detection API tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

When I use the labelImg (https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to draw bounding boxes around my objects to output the annotation.xml file, it gives the coordinates of the bounding box. I use these annotations to feed into object detection model (ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco & faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco) in tensorflow. The output of the predictions (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) are from 0 - 1.

Are the inputs in my annotation.xml normalized to 0 - 1? I want to know this as I would like to obtain IOU by inputting the ground truth and predicted bounding box into my own IOU function. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you feed your model with a tf.record file, it contains your image and normalized coordinates of your bounding box. So you conversion from .xml files to a tf.record file will also normalize your bounding box coordinates.

Your models's output will be in normalized coordinates too. You can easily rescale them by multiplying with the image size:

```
x_min_abs = x_min_rel * image_width
x_max_abs = x_max_rel * image_width
y_min_abs = y_min_rel * image_height
y_max_abs = y_max_rel * image_height
```

Comment: I am confused about the edge cases here.  Suppose you have an image which is 100x100. 
It looks like x_rel = 0 maps to x_abs = 0 and x_rel = 1 map to x_abs = 100.  However, this implies the image has 101 on a dimension -- [0, 100] has 101 integer elements.  Does Tensorflow map both x_rel = 1 and x_rel = 0.99 to the last row in the image array?

Comment: That's a good question I can't answer right now. I'd assume that TF would use image_width=image_height=99 in that case.